# Insert custom class with template into std::map

Tags: c++, class, templates, stdmap

I have written my own class and I want to insert it into a map. See the example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>

template <class T>
class A {
public:
    T a;
    A() = default;
    ~A() = default;
    A(T i) { a = i; }
};

int main()
{
  std::pair<int,A<int>> p;
  p = std::make_pair<int,A<int>>(9,A<int>(1));

  std::map<int, A<int>> m;
  m.emplace(1,A<int>(1));
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get an enormous error. Please help interpret it. :)

See error here:
http://cpp.sh/9nc35

**EDIT:** 
I had the typo, thanks! Though, the other problem I was struggling with first arose now. Seems like it is because of the mutex? Why?

Comment: I would normally be all over you to post the error message as text in the post, but yeah... in this case ... I don't know...it's really long and it's not even obviously clear which part of it is the important one. Can't wait for concepts to be implemented in the standard library and get rid of these unreadable template errors.

Comment: The linked program doesn't give any compile errors. Was it modified? Similarly, please don't "fix" code in a question in a way that makes it no longer a question or makes existing answers incorrect or not applicable. If you then run into a different issue and need help, you can create another question about that.

Comment: I still have the problem, that it can't compile. I saw that I have to try and run it, before "get url"...

Comment: So now your question is mostly discussing a problem that no longer exists (and isn't exhibited in your code), but you have a new and different problem which you haven't described at all. This isn't a good way to use a Q&A site, because the questions and answers aren't usefully related any more. Just ask a new question _that describes your actual problem and shows any errors_.

Answer (score 1):

Your map is defined as:

```
std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<A<int>>>
```

But in the next line you're trying to pass an `std::pair<int, A<int>>` to `m.emplace()` as the key.

I think you just want to do:

```
m.emplace(9, std::make_unique<A<int>>(1));
//        ^
//        Not `p`
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert/emplace pair (pair<...>, A) into your map, while you've specified it's key as an int. You most-likely want `m.emplace(9,std::make_unique<A<int>>(1));` (see `9` instead of `p`) or just `m.insert(p);` (would work fine in your cpp.sh).

Furthermore, your use of `unique_ptr` here is most-likely wrong/unwarranted and only complicates things. See fixed up example here: http://cpp.sh/3d2hw

Also, you may study STL collections/see some basic examples over at https://en.cppreference.com (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map for some map construction examples).

Comment: Just FYI, `m.insert(p)` wouldn't work either since the `value_type` is expecting an `std::unique_ptr<A<int>>`, not a simple instance of `A<int>`.

Comment: @KarlNicoll I was referring to the linked code, since @pointerdk have only added `unique_ptr` in his SO questions (looks like out of frustration since it was applied inconsistently).

Comment: Ah I see! Yeah looking at the cpp.sh link, an `m.insert(p)` solution would work.